# MongoMapper - Full Text Search

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Using this command directly on the database I get the results I am after

```
db.products.find({$text: {$search: "some product"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

But using it in MongoMapper I am getting errors.
The search without the score field doesn't produce any errors

```
@products = Product.where(
    '$text' => {'$search' => @search_string}
)
```

However, when I try to add the sort field is where I get issues

```
@products = Product.where(
    '$text' => {'$search' => @search_string}, :score => {'$meta' => "textScore"}
)
```

> Mongo::OperationFailure at /search unknown operator: $meta

It also fails using the raw query method

```
@products = MongoMapper.database['products'].find(
    '$text' => {'$search' => @search_string}, :score => {'$meta' => "textScore"}
)
```

The full query I am trying to run is

```
 @products = Product.where(
    '$text' => {'$search' => @search_string},:score => {'$meta' => "textScore"}
).sort(:score => {'$meta' => "textScore"}).limit(5)
```

This gives the error

> Mongo::OperationFailure at /search must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys

Does anyone have suggestions of where I am going wrong? I assume I am using it wrong.

Installed version. mongo_mapper (0.14.0, 0.13.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user on the MongoMapper Google group has pointed me in the right direction

```
@products = Product.where(
'$text' => {'$search' => @search_string}).fields(:score => {'$meta' => "textScore"})
```